# Magento 1 Import - If "Use Default Value" checked, skip to default view?

Tags: magento-1.9, import, importexport, import-products

I'm starting to learn a bit about Magento import / export tool.

The problem I'm having is that our store consists from 2 stores:

```
 - Default View
  - Canada
  - USA
```

The way that we set it up is that Canada uses Default View and USA uses USA view.

The problem I get when importing is that if the import is set to Canada View, it unchecks the "Use Default Value" and enters the new value into that field under Canada View.

This creates confusion of editing products manually where multiple store views have different content for Default vs Canada vs USA.

Is there a way to setup up the import so that it skips to Default view if "Use Default Value" is checked?